# String formatting a python nested dict

Tags: python-3.x

```
bag_id = 'abcd'
result_str = "{'affiliate_details.affiliate_bag_id': '{bag_id}'}".format(bag_id)
```

I want the output result_str as "{'affiliate_details.affiliate_bag_id':'abcd' }"

It gives a key error - affiliate_details

I tried with unpacking them using **{'bag_id':'abcd'} in the format but it too gives the same result.
I think its assuming the kwarg for affiliate_details but how do I deal with a nested one?

Also tried providing this but it gives same error

```
result_str = "{'affiliate_details.affiliate_bag_id': '{bag_id}'}".format(**{'affiliate_details':'affiliate_details', 'bag_id':'abcd'})
```

Answer (score 2):

how can python know where to search for format placeholders?

You have to escape the curly braces you want as bare curly braces:

```
"{{'affiliate_details.affiliate_bag_id': '{bag_id}'}}".format(bag_id=bag_id)
```

maybe you'd better build a real dictionary and serialize it:

```
result_dict = {'affiliate_details.affiliate_bag_id': bag_id}
```

then:

```
str(result_dict)
```

or

```
json.dumps(result_dict)
```

(slight differences when using json, with `None` and booleans, but you can use indentation options)

Comment: I was actually using JSONBender and wanted to try it out in a single statement rather than calling a function and dumping json.
Thanks for your answer... :)

Comment: answer also applies to any third party json serializer/parser as well of course :)